# cant connect mongoClient URI to cloud

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, cloud

Hi my Client mongo wont connect to my db still worked yesterday but not today, i change nothing before and no way to acces on my database with client ,i can acces and manage on webconsole cloud but not with my back-end client.

my client :

```
client = MongoClient("mongodb+srv://<login>:<password>@chatapp.wbany.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase,retryWrites=true&w=majority")
```

[image]

Can someone Help me ?

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.